# Structuring code blocks in SciTE

Tags: scite

Is there an easy way to create a collapsible block of code in SciTE? I know it will create a block when using if/while (etc.) statements, and comment blocks, but what if I just want a block of code that will be active, to be able to collapse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the `#region` and `#endregion` tags if you wish to do that.  This will allow you to collapse the regions as necessary.

Of course this also depends on what language you are programming in; but, for the most part, that is the tag I use for most things in Scite.  You can expand/collapse them, just like any other type of collapsible tag:

[image: region tags in scite]